# Magento 2 : Get all values of dropdown attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to get custom attribute like this in product detail
[image]

How can i do that?

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: You want this in custom admin form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get all options

```
    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ...............................
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
       ............................... 
    ) {
        ...............................
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        ...............................
    }
     public function execute()
    {
        $attributeCode = "your_attributr_name";
        $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] > 0) {
                $arr[] = $option;
            }
        }
    }
```

Reference from [click here](https://webkul.com/blog/get-options-custom-attribute-magento-2/)